# Unmount my external hard drive in bash

Tags: bash, unmount

So, this should apparently be really simple, but had trouble finding any good answers online.

I have a mounted external usb hard drive.

I would like to unmount it, using bash. (Essentially I'm just looking for the equivalent bash command for right clicking on my external hard drive in nautilus and selecting 'unmount')

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The better answer can be found here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178638/eject-safely-remove-vs-umount/178648.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Searching for "Unmount Hard Drive Terminal" yields http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=842698.

russlar provides a solution:

> open terminal, and run `df -h`. this will tell you all the hard drives mounted. then, run `sudo umount /dev/<something>`, where `<something>` is the name of the hard drive that you want to unmount.

Comment: Sometimes the disk in not mounted, it has been reformated, but an old partition is always used as swap... How to eject ; not unmount ?

Comment: To whom might make the same mistake I did: note that the command is named `umount`, and not  `unmount`.

Comment: Now it shows this page. :D

Comment: @eltiare woo! It only took 9 years to have an impact on humanity!